# Netbeans 8.1 Module was needed and not found

Tags: java, netbeans, module, compatibility, netbeans-8

I am trying to restore a Netbeans project from some years ago and I'm having many problems because of the not installed modules.
I have been all the morning searching on the Internet and trying to download them to import via **Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add Plugins...**.
Some of them were correctly installed but the most of them seem to be already installed so I don't understand why are they not found.

My computer is running Windows 10.

Here I paste the output from the console.

> Warning - could not install some modules:
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.support - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.support - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.support - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.util/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.document - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.util/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.tools.storage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.tools.storage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.tools.storage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.util/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.tools.storage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.tools.storage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.debug - The module named
>   org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.debug - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.debug - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.debugger/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.debug - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.document would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.debug - The module named
>   org.netbeans.spi.viewmodel/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.debug - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.debug - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.team.commons - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.java.classpath/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.coverage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.java.classpath/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.coverage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.coverage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.gsf.codecoverage was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.coverage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.embedder/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.coverage - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.search - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.search - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.search - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.search - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.search - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.util/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.editor.search - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.editor/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.common was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.document would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.html.custom - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi.base - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.checkstyle - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.checkstyle - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.checkstyle - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.xml.xam/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.checkstyle - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.model/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.checkstyle - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.embedder/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.maven.checkstyle - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.lib.nbjavac - The module named
>   org.netbeans.libs.javacimpl/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.lib.nbjavac - The module named
>   org.netbeans.libs.javacapi was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.lib - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.lib - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.common was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.lib - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.lib - The module named
>   org.netbeans.libs.antlr3.runtime was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.lib - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.css.lib would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.common was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.diff/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.document would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.css.model - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.commons - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.team.commons would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.commons - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.java.classpath/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi.base would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.document would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.util/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module named
>   org.netbeans.libs.lucene/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing - The module named
>   org.netbeans.spi.tasklist/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.java.classpath/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.extexecution/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.diff/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner.ui - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi.base would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner.ui - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.java.classpath/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.core.ide/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.diff/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.hudson was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi.base would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.libs.commons_net/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner.ui would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.hudson.ui - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.java.classpath/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis - The module named
>   org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.refactoring.api was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi.base would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.findbugs.installer - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.findbugs.installer - The module named
>   org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.css.lib would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.support would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.common was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.fold/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0-1 was needed and not
>   found.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.java.classpath/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.options.editor/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.util/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.editor/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.codetemplates/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.css.editor/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.lexer/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.document would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.nodejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.nodejs - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.nodejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.editor/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.nodejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.common was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.nodejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.nodejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.nodejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.knockout - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.knockout - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.knockout - The module
>   named org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.knockout - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi.base would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.knockout - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.indexing would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.knockout - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.knockout - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.extjs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.extjs - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.extjs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.extjs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.prototypejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.prototypejs - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.prototypejs - The module
>   named org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.prototypejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.prototypejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.prototypejs - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.css.editor/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jquery - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.css.lib would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.common was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.fold/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.editor would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.css.editor/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.csl.api/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.lexer/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.document would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.html.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/3 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.javascript2.jade - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.java.source.base - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.classfile/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.java.source.base - The module named
>   org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.java.source.base - The module named
>   org.netbeans.api.java/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.java.source.base - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi.base would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.java.source.base - The module named
>   org.netbeans.libs.javacimpl/1 was needed and not found.
>     org.netbeans.modules.java.source.base - The module
>   org.netbeans.lib.nbjavac would also need to be installed.
>   ...